# Где в Android Studio указывается текущая версия приложения?

Tags: android, java

Хочу выложить приложение в плей маркет для альфа-тестирования. Не могу найти, где указывается версия программы (в манифесте не увидел), чтобы позже её увеличивать. Прошу подсказки. Не в build.gradle в versionCode ли?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В корневом теге `manifest` в `AndroidManifest.xml`, атрибуты `android:versionCode` и `android:versionName`.

Comment: А build.gradle просто меняет его в манифесте при сборке

Comment: Хм. Что-то не вижу здесь android:versionCode, хотя в build.gradle стоит 1 и "0.1" соответственно. Может, не в тот манифест смотрю? https://yadi.sk/i/05KOQyCicN9DB

Comment: Ну так в build.gradle эти значения приоритетнее. В манифесте можете не указывать в таком случае. Но если будете потом собирать не грейдлом, то он у вас не соберётся просто. Надо просто понимать, что делает грейдл - это "внешняя" система, которая приводит код к сборке и удобна для версионности. А когда собирается - оно уже берёт из манифеста.